# Push an existing repository when creating a new repository always fail?

Tags: github, terminal

So every time I try to create a new repository and follow the Github instruction here.

```
…or push an existing repository from the command line
git remote add origin 
https://github.com/menghaohsu/JavaAkkaCountWordInDirectory.git
git push -u origin master
```

It doesn't push the file in JavaAkkaCountWordInDirectory to Github but push repository. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: "It doesn't push the file in JavaAkkaCountWordInDirectory" --- what does this mean?

Comment: You have to be a little more specific. Do you have a local repository already created? If so, you can try to push it, if not, init the local repo first, add the origin and then push.

Comment: @zerkms Sorry for the mislead, I have a filename call JavaAkkaCountWordInDirectory and I try to push all the file in the directory into this new repository.

Comment: You do not "push" files. You commit them.

Comment: @JesusA.Sanchez I have a local directory and I want to push this to the new repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give you a few steps over here.

I assume you created your repo via GitHub.com web interface.

Locally you should have done all of the following steps prior to pushing the files to the remote.

1. **git init** --> This will initialize your local repo
2. **git remote add origin {remote address}**
3. **git add {filename here | . }** --> With this you add the file(s) to the staging area
4. **git commit** --> This command commits your changes (You have to add a message)
5. **git -u push origin master**

That should do the trick

Comment: It works! But can I know why if I do
1. git remote add origin 
2. https://github.com/menghaohsu/JavaAkkaCountWordInDirectory.git
3. git push -u origin master
And it pushes some file to this repository. I assume those files are in my git remote. Is it possible to delete those files in git remote?

Comment: Yes, you can delete them via the Web interface or delete them locally, use **git add .**, commit your changes and use **git push -a** to push the deletes to the remote repo as well. If you miss the -a, no deletes will be pushed to the remote repo.